# Use a Font in VSCode

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode for few weeks. I am new in VSCode. How can I use "FiraCode" font in VSCode ? I am trying to use like below

[image]

Comment: [posting text in images is not useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). Isn't it faster and better to copy and paste the text here?

Comment: I don't think you only need ONE font. You can add the font at the beginning of the default fonts. When this font doesn't contain a specific character, VSCode will use the second font automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You have two quotes around the font name.**

Change the line to this:
`"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",`

---

*Still not working? Follow these steps:*

To use the font in VS Code, ensure it is installed first.

1. Download a font file, such as this [OTF version of FiraCode-Regular](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/raw/master/distr/otf/FiraCode-Regular.otf)
2. Open the font preview by double-clicking the font file. Make sure it is the font you want.
3. Click Install. Provide administrator permissions if requested.
4. Open your user settings in VS Code (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Comma</kbd>)
5. Change the Font Family setting to `"Fira Code"`

Answer (score 0):

This popped up on my feed in 2022, I guess due to an edit, but there is a little more to the story than what has been said here.

Where the answer is correct:

> Adding the setting **`"editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code"`** to your `settings.json` file will add Fira Code

...but the entire character set of Fira Code is far from equipped.

if you look at the docs **[HERE](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#whats-in-the-box)** you will see a whole bunch of different characters & ligatures available, and to use those you have to add the following setting:

```
"editor.fontLigatures":"'zero', 'ss02', 'ss03', 'ss04', 'ss05', 'calt'",
```

###### For more on VSCode & Stylistic sets, @SEE [The "2019 October Release Notes" - #stylistic-sets.](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_font-feature-settings)

The setting above is an example of a configuration that is popular, what is added to the `"editor.fontLigatures"` setting can be customized.

Fira has good documentation for the stylistic sets & ligatures that can be enabled, but I like the list that is posted **[HERE](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/1203)** - *this list is direct and straight to the point.*